# How to assign symbols to the data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbols

I am trying to plot some data with categories. However, I couldn't manage to plot my data according to the categories and show a legend for them. Therefore, I am asking a little bit help to this issue.
Example data;

| Name | Brand | Mt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Enes | Renault | 2.6 |
| Avni | Tofaş | 2.38 |
| Asaf | Tofaş | 3.06 |

My experience, I have managed to plot these data with two plot command overlaying each other grouping them by Brand. However, this time, one group of data has 2 line (as Tofaş has two data)  and the other has only one line data (as in Renault). Thus, x-axis is confusing and not giving a healty graph.
The other issue with this, I can't label the x-axis according to Name when I plot two graph overlaying.

```
figure
plot(table.Mt, 'o');

xtickangle(90)

sizes = size(table.Name);
a1 = gca;
a1.XTick = [1:sizes];
a1.XTickLabel = table.Name;
```

[the output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU7uk.png)

```
[Ism, Ind] =ismember(table.Brand, 'Tofaş');
plot(Ism, 'o')
```

[the output of second code block above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccqoA.png)

As you can see, when I select only spesific Brand. The rest of arrray filling with zero (0) which I don't want to.
What I want is that plotting all data with spesific symbols for each Brand together.

Thank you
Enes

Comment: Do you have the data in this MD format, or is it just part of the question? Could you please show the raw content of your file?

Comment: I have the data in excel. And. I am using in gnuplot like txt file. Raw content is exactly like this and there are 5 more brands and 15 names, too.

Comment: So, are you trying to create a `histogram`? Also, did you have a look at `xticlabels`? Please do some research effort, show us your (not necessarily working) code you got so far and state exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't understand the goal. Apparently the Brand has duplicates. Are the names unique? What is Mt? What should be the x-axis and what should be the y-axis? What should be the plot type, `with boxes` grouped by Brand? Please clarify!

Comment: I did them all.

Comment: @EnesKasikci Your code doesn't look like gnuplot code. What are you actually using?